# How to get notify whenever a file is started to upload in FTP server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, notifications, ftp

I want to get notify whenever the file is started to upload in FTP server and whenever there is no file upload in the ftp directory more than 10 minute. Is there any method to tell me that file is started to upload in FTP server (in Python)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: are you using `ftplib` for uploading?

Comment: We are using some devices to upload it

Comment: @KlausD. I don't we know how to approach it . I search it on Internet but I wasn't able to get any method to solve my query

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. A possible interpretation is that you manage the server and want to get somehow informed if new files gets uploaded (if and how this can be done depends on the server). Another interpretation might be that you want to write a FTP client which realizes when new files got uploaded (need to be polling). And there are probably more possible interpretations of your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I want to get informed if new files are uploaded in FTP. And i want to write a python script to do that .

Comment: @parasjain: you basically repeat your question without actually dealing with my comment about possible interpretations of the question. Please add sufficient detail to your question so that it is clear what you have and what you are trying to do and where exactly you have a problem to implement what you want.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your second interpretaion is correct . I am using FileZilla

Comment: @parasjain: Then all what you can do is connect with your Python code to the server and poll all the time if a new file shows up in the directory. This can be easily done with ftplib (look at the documentation how to connect to a server and get a directory listing) but is not friendly to the server at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Is there any friendly way to do that in the server ?

Comment: @parasjain: to cite myself: *"if and how this can be done depends on the server"*. So maybe, but no details are known about this server and what level of access you have to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below code will solve your problem you just need to connect it with your server. You can try in your local directory also.

```
import os, time
path_to_watch = "test_ftp/"
flag = 0
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
  time.sleep (10)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  print added
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added:
    print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
    if flag==0:
        print "Notify me once"
    flag =1
  if removed: print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
  if after == before:
    print "No files uploaded in 10 minutes"
    break
  before = after
```